# what happened to my glass reflection?

Tags: texturing, uv, glass, reflection

I am currently following blender guru's beginner tutorial following instructions every step of the way.

As soon as I added the droplet texture at the end of part 5, level 3: condensation, the glass on the cup started acting more like a double sided mirror. I went back and checked all my steps and can not fix the issue.

Kindly see images below of the renders before and after the droplets were added.
Also an image of the node tree

Download blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14cgNa2obNQeCxPaCypIecraDncKC0x-S/view?usp=sharing)

[image: before adding water droplets]

[image: after adding droplets]

node tree
[image: node tree]

Comment: What does your shader node tree look like?

Comment: tree node added

Comment: Can you attach your blender file?

Comment: blender file added

Answer (score 3):

I messed around with it for a while and there was definitely something weird going on with your object.

[image]

If you check the *Face Orientation* overlay you'll see the normals on your cup are inside out.

[image]

Select your cup, and switch to *Edit Mode*.  Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and select *Recalculate Outside*.

Everything should render properly afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connect the *Alpha* output (or even try *Color Output* alternatively) of your *Image Texture* and connect it to the *Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF* node.

[image: edited node]

Comment: connected the alpha of the image-texture to the principle BDSF and nothing changed. i am assuming it has to do with the original glass material or it has to do with the uv seems ive selected.